# Linq Select List if Records present in another List

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 different Lists with 2 properties named EmpId & EntryDate.
From the List 1, I want to select only those records which are present in List2.

Pseudo Code :-

```
var list1 = ctx.tblHoli.Select(m=>new{m.EmpId, m.EntryDate}).ToList();
var list2 = ctx.tblWeek.Select(m=>new{m.EmpId, m.EntryDate}).ToList();
```

In a `list3`, I want records from `list1` which are present in `list2`

What is the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: That's called an "intersection", try reading [ask] and sharing your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the intersection:

```
var list3 = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```